# How is it possible to delete a contact with the edit permission for a group?

Tags: contacts, groups, permissions, acl

I have a user and want to give her limited access to contacts. She is supposed to view all contacts but create/edit/delete of only one specific group.

I gave her Edit permission via ACLs fot that group. She can edit the contacts in the group but the Delete operation does not appear for those contacts.

I cannot give Delete access via Magage ACLs because only View & Edit permissions are selectable for a group of contacts.

What can I do? Is it a bug or am I missing something?

[For creating a new contact, I disabled adding a contact in general and created a specific profile with a new contact form for her, that adds the new contact to that group - this works fine. She, however, cannot delete what she has created.]

CiviCRM version 4.7.11 on WordPress 4.7.2.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  This looks like a good question. You could improve it by editing it to add the version of CiviCRM and the CMS you are using (e.g. Drupal, WordPress or Joomla).  Some answers may vary depending on what version you are using.